# Microsoft chart grid lines not drawn at 'whole' numbers

Tags: c#, data-visualization, mschart, dundas

When the Microsoft chart control is zoomed in, the values of the labels and grid lines often looks like 38.2, 39.2, 40.2, 41.2 ... rather than 38,39,40,41.  I tried to set the interval offset to correct this by using the code shown below without success.

```
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset = myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum % 1;
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum % 1;
```

What is the proper way to get the major and minor grid-lines and labels to be drawn starting at a specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems might be caused by margins being added. Make sure you set

```
myChart.ChartArea[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```